# js files doesn't load when changing state ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I hope you can help me out or give me a hint to solve my problem.

I am making an app using angularjs and material design lite (css and js).
My problem is that  the material design js file doesn't take affect on the partials once the state changes and basically I lost all the functionality that material design library provides me.

this is my code so far
index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Appy2go</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" type="text/css">
  <!-- Material Design Lite -->
  <script src="dist/js/material.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/material.pink-blue.min.css">
  <!-- <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.0/material.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css"> -->
  <!-- Material Design icon font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/auth0/angular-storage/master/dist/angular-storage.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/auth0/angular-jwt/master/dist/angular-jwt.js"></script>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="modules/home/home.js"></script>
  <script src="modules/signin/signin.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app-wrapper" ui-view></div>
  <!--THIS BUTTON WORKS AS SUPPOSED TO BE-->
  <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
    Button
  </button>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('app',[
  'ui.router',
  'app.home',
  'app.signin'
])
.config(function($urlRouterProvider){
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
})
.controller('AppController',function($scope){
  console.log("ready");
})
```

home module

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-drawer mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout-icon"></div> <!-- IT SHOULD DISPLAY AN ICON ON SMALL DEVICES -->
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <span class="mdl-layout__title">App Name</span>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout__title">App Name</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">link 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">link 2</a>
      <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">link 3</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <div>Content</div>
    <!-- Colored FAB button with ripple -->
    <!-- Accent-colored raised button with ripple -->
    <!-- THIS BUTTON DOESN'T WORK AS SUPPOSED TO BE -->
    <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
      Button
    </button>
  </main>
  <footer class="mdl-mini-footer">
    <div class="mdl-mini-footer__right-section">
      <div class="mdl-logo">Appy2go</div>
      <ul class="mdl-mini-footer__link-list">
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Privacy & Terms</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

home.js

```
angular.module('app.home',[
  'ui.router'
])
.config(function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider.state('home',{
      url:'/',
      controller: 'HomeController',
      templateUrl: 'modules/home/home.html',
    })
})
.controller('HomeController',function($scope,$http){
  console.log("Ready");
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular has to know when to look for changes in the variables.  If you have non-angular code changing things then you have to tell angular to rerun the digest cycle.

Here's an example where I wrapped the jQuery Dialog function in Angular.  I'm having to manually tell Angular to WATCH and APPLY.

```
app.directive("dialog", function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        dialog:"=",
      },
      controller: function($scope) { 
        $scope.$watch("dialog", function(){
          if($scope.dialog){
            $scope.open();
          }else{
            $scope.close();
          }
        });
      },
      link: {
        pre: function(scope, element, attributes) {
          scope.open = function() {
            element.dialog({
              height: attributes.height,
              width: attributes.width
            });
          };
          scope.close = function() {
            element.dialog("close");
          };
        },
        post: function(scope, element, attributes) {
          scope.open();
          element.on("dialogclose", function(){
            if(scope.dialog){
              scope.dialog = false;
              scope.$apply();
            }
          });
        }
      },
    };
  });
```

Rest of the code is here.
https://plnkr.co/edit/myBzYyL2BHOP8CtRpqrr?p=info

Comment: that's a lot work, I am using a bunch of components that material design lite library provides, I would spend most of the time doing that you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Your routing code should be in the first module which is the main module. I feel that's where your problem is, I am not on a PC right now to be able to replicate your code and test. But change that first.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, but thank you anyway